# Converting unknown characters to readable characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading information from a page like [this](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/669.shtml) and putting it in my own database. I'm interested in data like the name and classification. In this example the name is `Flabébé` and the classification is `Single Bloom Pokémon`. When I view the information on screen I keep getting a � for every `é` (e-acute). If I store it in my database it cuts off before every e-acute.

I tried the many suggestions that are on the internet but none seem to work. I can't wrap my head around it. I ended up with this, but no results:

```
html_entity_decode($classification, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

The PHP page charset is set to utf-8 in the header, and also in the HTML header. The charset of my database connection is also set to utf-8. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by, "When I view the information on screen"?

Comment: I visited the Flabébé page - it is not utf-8 coded, it uses text encoding: windows-1252

Comment: @Jacey I mean simply echoing the result. Sorry for being to cryptic.

Comment: What method are you using to scrape the page? Is it possible that the method you're using only works with ascii characters? The reason I ask is because the HTML code shows `<td>Flab&#233;b&#233;</td>` for Flabébé, meaning those accent égu are in HTML symbols.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. I'm using this to scrape: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net. Not sure why those HTML characters aren't showing.

Comment: Most of the names are actually just `Flabébé`, so not HTML decoded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to Tom K's answer. It's using text encoding Windows-1252. So I have to convert it to UTF-8 like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding($classification, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
```